# Is this C++ reference assignment correct?

Tags: c++, reference, variable-assignment

In this simplified example, my question is: am I doing a legal assignment inside Action::setUser()?

```
class User {
private:
   int age;
public:
   int getAge() { return age; }
};

class Action {
private:
   User user;
public:
   void setUser(User &u) {
      user = u;
   }
};

int main() {
   User u;
   Action a;
   a.setUser(u);
   return 0;
}
```

What makes me noise is,

- what happens to Action's "user" attribute when setUser is called? is it destroyed? was it ever constructed?
- what happens if I call setUser for a second time?
- if I remove the "&" symbol in setUser, everything would be fine, right? because that would be like passing a copy of the parameter, right?

I'm worried that I'm doing crazy things with memory because attribute is not being correctly destroyed...

Thank you

---

**Edited on Mon Feb 18, 2013**

Thank you so much! I really appreciate all of your responses...

I didn't know the compiler provided a default overloaded assignment operator. Now I that know everything makes perfect sense...

Thanks again.

Comment: aside from likely being better if that were `const User& u`, the assignment is fine. It will copy the user over without an intermediate copy to a by-val parameter. Action's existing user is not destroyed `setUser(u)`, rather, will "overwrite" via an assignment operator. If you want you can control how that is done via writing a `User::operator =(const User& u)` yourself. Regarding a second call, same thing as the first. Finally, Removing the & *will* introduce at least one extra copy.

Comment: I wonder about last sentence you wrote: *"I'm worried that I'm doing crazy things with memory because attribute is not being correctly destroyed"* - What do you mean by *"being correctly destroyed"*? How do you observe this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what happens to Action's "user" attribute when setUser is called?

The *assignment operator* (provided by the compiler, as you haven't defined a custom one) is called, which simply performs a member-wise copy from `u` to `user`.

> is it destroyed?

No.

> Was it ever constructed?

Yes.

> what happens if I call setUser for a second time?

The same thing.

> if I remove the "&" symbol in setUser, everything would be fine, right?

As far as the assignment to `user` is concerned, this would make no difference.  Passing by reference simply means that no copy of the argument is made when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine. It's just assigning from `u` that you've defined in main directly to `a.user`. The reference parameter avoids making an extra copy to pass to `a.setUser`.

When you create an `Action` it contains a default-constructed `User` object. You're then assigning a value to that `User`. This isn't (IMO) the best design (I'd rather see the `User` constructed with the correct value) but it's all entirely valid.

The assignment does nothing to create or destroy the existing value. The `Action` object will be destroyed when it goes out of scope, and that will destroy the `User` object it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

- It is not destroyed but overwritten (copy-assignment). And yes, it was constructed before.
- The same as the first time.
- If you removed the `&`, you would pass a copy. It doesn't make things wrong or right though.

Notes:

- Use const, both on memberfunctions and on passed parameters.
- You need to at least consider controlling copying and assignment. This should be explained in any better C++ introduction or FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Action {
private:
   User user;
}
```

defines an private member of type `User`. It is an object with automatic storage duration, that it constructed while object of type `Action` is being constructed. It's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of an object of type `Action`.

Now in this method:

```
void setUser(User &u) {
    user = u;
}
```

`u` is a reference to the object whose attributes (members) will be used to set attributes of `user` by using the ***assignment operator***.

And if you remove `&` here, you will change passing by reference to passing by value, which means that copy of object passed to this method will be created upon its call.